# Admin filters for django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

Django admin provides very basic view for applying filters on List pages but we have several uses cases where we want multi select, multi search, range filtering. These cases include applying filtering on related fields and reverse related fields as well

We explored several packages

- https://github.com/modlinltd/django-advanced-filters
- https://github.com/silentsokolov/django-admin-rangefilter
- https://github.com/lukasvinclav/django-admin-numeric-filter

but none seems to fit our use cases well without fiddling with base model admin.

Are there alternatives to these ?
If creating own custom filters how are you handling such uses cases ? - any ideas / tips / suggestion to start with ?

I did get some idea for search here - https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-add-a-text-filter-to-django-admin-5d1db93772d8

- for multiple options to search, planning to use comma separated values and then split that in backend
- confused on how to implement for multi select choices

Answer (score 10):

If you mean you want to filter through Boolean fields, go to admin.py and add `list_filter` in your `modelAdmin`.
For example:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = [
         "first_boolean_field",
         "second_bollean_field",
         "third_boolean_field"
    ]
    search_fields = (
        "field1",
        "field2",
    )

admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
```

`list_filter` will allow you to filter by Boolean fields multiple times and `search_field` will allow you search by fields in the tuple.

Comment: No, this doesn't allow us to search for multiple values in a particular field. This allows to search for a single value in multiple fields